# Munkres - Chapter 2 - Section 18 - Problem 8 (b)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity

I want to know if my application of the pasting lemma is right. Thank you for your comments.

**The pasting lemma.** *Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $h$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$, $A,B$ be closed sets in $X$ such that $X=A\cup B$, $f$ be a function from $A$ to $Y$ and $g$ be a function from $B$ to $Y$. If $f,g$ are continuous, $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in A\cap B$ and
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)\impliedby x\in A\\
g(x)\impliedby x\in B
\end{cases}$$
then $h$ is continuous.*

**Lemma 1.** *Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be an ordered set with order topology and $f,g:X\to Y$ be continuous functions. Then $\{x\in X : f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.*

**Lemma 2.** *Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $A$ is a subespace of $X$ then $f|A$ is continuous, where $f|A$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$.*

**Theorem.** *Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be an ordered set with order topology and $f,g:X\to Y$ be continuous functions. Show that the function $h:X\to Y$ defined by $h(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is continuous.*

*Proof.* For proving this theorem I am going to apply The pasting lemma. It's given that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and that $h:X\to Y$.  Set
$$A:=\{x\in X : f(x)\leq g(x)\}\ \text{and}\ B:=\{x\in X : g(x)\leq f(x)\},$$
then, by Lemma 1, we have that $A,B$ are closed in $X$. If $x\in A\cup B$ then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and from the last we deduce that $x\in X$ since in any case we have that $x\in X$; so $A\cup B\subseteq X$. If $x\in X$ then $f(x),g(x)\in Y$ and since $Y$ is and ordered set we have that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ or $f(x)>g(x)$, from the first case we get that $x\in A$ so $x\in A\cup B$, from the second case we get $x\in B$ so $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in X$ implies that $x\in A\cup B$ and from this we deduce that $X\subseteq A\cup B$. Since $A\cup B\subseteq X$ and $X\subseteq A\cup B$ we get that $X=A\cup B$. Set
$$f':= f|A\ \text{and}\ g' := g|B,$$
where $f|A$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$ and $g|B$ of $g$ to $B$, then $f': A\to Y$ and $g': B\to Y$. We note that $A$ with the subspace topology in $X$ is a subspace of $X$, then, by lemma 2, we have that $f|A$ is continuous and then $f'$ is continuous, by a similar argument we get that $g'$ is continuous. We note that
$$x\in A\cap B\implies x\in A,B\implies f(x)\leq g(x)\leq f(x)\implies f(x)=g(x)\implies f'(x)=g'(x),$$
the last implication holds because if $x\in A$ then $f'(x)=f(x)$ and if $x\in B$ then $g'(x)=g(x)$. We note that
$$x\in A\implies f(x)\leq g(x)\implies \min\{f(x),g(x)\}=f(x)\implies h(x)=f(x)\implies h(x)=f'(x),$$
the last implication holds because if $x\in A$ then $f'(x)=f(x)$. Similarly we get that $x\in B\implies h(x)=g'(x)$, then
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)\impliedby x\in A\\
g(x)\impliedby x\in B
\end{cases}$$
and therefore, by The pasting Lemma, we conclude that $h$ is continuous.

Comment: The only correction to make in you last theorem and its proof is to replace "ordered" by "totally ordered".